# Sweet Alert inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

I have a javascript function to call sweetalert based on the userinput but sweet alert is not working inside bootstrap model.

can anyone help me out

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>   

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" id="input1" onblur="alerts()">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function alerts()
{
  var inputs = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  if(inputs < 2)
  {
  swal('Not Valid', 'Enter another','warning');
  }
}
```

Comment: alert = function() {  if you want to call if from html  http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/oj5cfp6j/

Comment: @AndrewBone, you should post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just needed to reorder your function slightly

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/oj5cfp6j/

```js
alerts = function () {
  var inputs = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  if (inputs < 2) {
    swal('Not Valid', 'Enter another', 'warning');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" id="input1" onblur="alerts()">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not big fan of JavaScript so can't sure why it's not working with `blur()`, but you can do it with jQuery `keyup` function

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#input1').keyup(function () {
    var inputs = $(this).val();
    if (inputs < 2) {
      swal('Not Valid', 'Enter another', 'warning');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="input1" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you run the above snippet, did you enter the value `1` to check and did you include all files like included in answer, CSS and JS, see what's missing in your code cause it's working in snippet if you enter `1` in input

Comment: This only checks when you type, OP wants it on focus out

Comment: @AndrewBone ahhh, OP can use `change` or `keydown` function, my opinion `user experience` always comes first, so it's better this way if you instantly notify the user there is something wrong rather then alert when user click or do anything else outside the input

Comment: @Shehary this way they get a notification between every key stroke though  (actually just if they press space)

Comment: @AndrewBone no they only get notification when certain condition met which in this case is `< 2` and they don't lose focus on input when alert closed which I think is better `user experience` rather then type > click outside > alert show > close alert > click on input again to type